# Prevent deleting an object through an interface

Tags: c++, interface, destructor

Let's suppose that in C++ I have an interface class `Interface`, which has only pure virtual functions. Then, other class definitions derive from this interface and provide an implementation for the pure virtual functions.

Now, is there a way to prevent an object to be deleted via an `Interface*` pointer? I have tried deleting the constructor but then derived classes can't be destroyed either.

The idea being to pass object pointer while being clear on the fact that ownership isn't passed with the pointer. I know there are other ways to achieve this, I'm just curious whether it's doable in C++.

Comment: *The idea being to pass object pointer while being clear on the fact that ownership isn't passed with the pointer.* This is what smart pointers are for.  If you want to participate in ownership, pass a `unique` or `shared` pointer.  A raw pointer should only ever be considered a non-owning observer.  If you adopt that policy in your code base, you don't need to worry about accidental delete's.  You can even add a layer of abstraction if you really want to and make a `observer_ptr` type which doesn't do anything to the pointer it gets accept provide access.

Comment: How do you delete an object via an Interface* pointer? I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Your interface should either have a _public virtual destructor_ (which then allows deleting the object via the interface pointer), or a _protected destructor_.  Depending on your compiler and warning levels, the compiler may complain if the protected destructor isn't also virtual.  If you do interface classes a lot or on larger projects, you may want to use the [Non-Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the destructor protected:

```
struct interface {
    protected:
        virtual ~interface(){}
};

struct concrete : interface {};

int main(){
    //interface f; // error

    //interface* f2 = new concrete(); 
    //delete f2;                       // error

    concrete c;

    concrete* c2 = new concrete();
    delete c2;
}
```

However, note that it is `delete f2;` that issues the error, so a user might be tempted to `new interface` and then leak it.

Also note that this is technically possible but wont solve any problem. You would always need to know the concrete type otherwise you cannot delete an object, making the interface basically useless for polymorphism.

Comment: You won't be able to `new interface` if `interface` has pure virtual functions.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I know, the point was just to demonstrate that `delete f2;` is an error. If you like replace the example with `interface* f2 = new concrete(); delete f2;`

Comment: @MaxLanghof I read the question as being only about the "doable in C++" while "there are other [better] ways to achieve this" would be a different quesiton